# The Hidden markers show in cluster icon in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I used google map api in my project with cluster (MarkerClusterer)

```
var markers=[];
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
{ //create marker
    markers.push(marker):
}
 markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
// then .. in another part .. i do .
for(var j=0;j<200;j++)
{
markers[j].setVisible(false);
}
markerclusterer.draw();
```

the problem ::

its hide the 200 markers but in cluster icon its still ..

i mean .. ( if i calculate the numbers shown in cluster icon =1000) . but actually 800 markes is visible and 200 are hidden.)

how to make the cluster icon =800 only.
..thnx

Answer (score 4):

when you finished your loop, add .repaint() method, so it will update counters.
But the main thing is that you need to add/remove these shown/hidden markers from the markerclusterer object automatically on hide/show marker

```
var markers=[], markerclusterer;

markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, []);

for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
{ 
    //create marker
    markerclusterer.addMarker(marker, true);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'visible_changed', function(){
        if ( marker.getVisible() ) {
            markerclusterer.addMarker(marker, true);
        } else {
            markerclusterer.removeMarker(marker, true);
        }                   
    });
}
// then .. in another part .. i do .
for(var j=0;j<200;j++)
{
    markers[j].setVisible(false);
}
markerclusterer.repaint();
```

Hope that will help somebody.

Comment: you're welcome. Just hope that it might help somebody else :)

Comment: What was the other solution? Why not post it?

Comment: the problem with that code is that when removing marker from clusterer, it also removes it from map... very annoying when you want to just hide the markers, but not remove them from map...